# Request body not showing in Nest.js + Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, nestjs, nestjs-swagger, nestjs-config

My controller code is something like this.

```
@Controller('customer')
export class CustomerController{

    constructor(private readonly customerService: CustomerService){}

    @Post('lookup')
    async someMethod(@Body() body:any){

        console.log("BEGIN -- CustomerController.someMethod");
```

I am expecting to see in Swagger a place where I can input some text as a request body but instead I see this

[image]

Comment: Are you using the Swagger Plugin?

Comment: in my package.json I have "@nestjs/swagger": "^4.4.0",

Comment: In your `nest-cli.json` are you using the swagger plugin?

Comment: I am not really sure what plugin means here but this is what's in my nest-cli.json

Comment: {
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src"
}

Comment: @p0tta yes, you'll have to install package

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So it sounds like there's a few things going on here. The Swagger UI is a helper tool for sending in requests, but to do that it needs to know the shape of the request body. `any` is not good enough. If you're looking for a tool that allows you to send in anything, curl or postman are you best bets (at least for free).

Nest has a [Swagger plugin](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger#plugin) that will read through your Typescript code and decorate your types and method accordingly, but you have to opt in to enable it. Otherwise, you need to use the decorators from the `@nestjs/swagger` package to tell Swagger what types are expected in and out of the methods.

So long as the type that corresponds to `@Body()` has swagger decorators **or** you enable the swagger plugin **and** have a valid class, the swagger UI should show up as expected, but with the above and using type `any` it won't do you any good.

Comment: Do I need to install the Swagger plugin or does it come out of the box if I have this in my package.json? "@nestjs/swagger": "^4.4.0"

Comment: The link to the docs in my answer clearly explains how to set up the plugin to work.

Comment: I tried with setting body type to an interface, still it did not work. Finally, replacing the interface as class worked. Thanks...

Comment: Interfaces don't exist at runtime, so there's no metadata to reflect about them.

Answer (score 20):

Add  @ApiProperty()

```
export class User{

 @ApiProperty()
  name:string
 
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution to having a Request body example value in swagger ui and this was it thanks !

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using dto for body.

Refer to [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters).

Example of a DTO is shown below.

**DTO:**

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class CreateCatDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  age: number;

  @ApiProperty()
  breed: string;
}
```

**Function**

```
@Post()
async create(@Body() createCatDto: CreateCatDto) {
  //Do Stuff.
}
```

`@ApiProperty` adds properties to swagger request.

It should show something like this:
[image]

```
@Post()
@ApiBody({ type: CreateCatDto })
async create(@Body() createCatDto: CreateCatDto) {
  //Do Stuff.
}
```

The above code is going to give output similar to below where your schema is also going to be documented:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

My endpoint accepts unknown key/value data and I was having the same problem (I tried *any, unknown, Record<string, any>, object, {}*). Finally `@Body() data: Map<string, any>` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

try it like this:

```
@ApiBody({description: "body:any someMethod"})
@Post('lookup')
async someMethod(@Body() body:any){
console.log("BEGIN -- CustomerController.someMethod");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with *.dto.ts and add the below code in nest-cli.json unser compilerOptions. You do not need to add @ApiProperty on each field

```
"plugins": [
  {
    "name": "@nestjs/swagger",
    "options": {
      "introspectComments": true
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Actually - the *.dto.ts is a subtle nuance that I wasn't expecting.  This helped me - I went from no success with <filename>.request-body-dto.ts to success with <filename>.request-body.dto.ts